# How do I have more complex layouts in `react-admin` "Show" and "Edit" and "Create" screens?

Tags: layout, react-admin

I'm trying to build on react-admin. The base structure is this:

```
<Show {...props} >
  <SimpleShowLayout>
    <TextField source="id" />
    <TextField source="name" />
  </SimpleShowLayout>
</Show>
```

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
<Show {...props} >
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-sm-6">
      <TextField source="id" />
    </div>
    <div className="col-sm-6">
      <TextField source="name" />
    </div>
  </div>
</Show>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to update our documentation about this. We recently decoupled components with logic, that we name XXXController (ListController, CreateController, etc) in the `ra-core` package and UI components (List, Create, etc) in the `ra-ui-materialui` package which the controllers.

Think about the `react-admin` package as a distribution of react-admin with material-ui UI. When heavy customization is needed, you can use the controllers directly.

For now, you'll have to explore the source code to fully understand how to use them.

Here's an example:

```
import { ShowController, ShowView, SimpleShowLayout, TextField } from 'react-admin';

const UserShow = props => (
    <ShowController {...props}>
        {controllerProps => 
            // You're on your own here
        }
    </ShowController>
);
```

Comment: That works, but I lose the header, which I need to modify anyway. How would you add the title, and page frame back in?

Comment: I got it. For anyone else... I wrapped my content in <Paper>, then added inside it:                 <Header title="Entity" actions={this.headerActions()}></Header>

Comment: Yes, because `ShowController` does not display anything. You really are on your own ;)

Comment: Isn't there any way to have some extra bits in the form - like <p>, <h3> elements even?  Every single element in a <SimpleForm> appears to be treated like a component - and passed props which cause errors/warnings in the console.  Some of the layout needs lots of classic HTML treatment but it seems <SimpleForm> only expects specific components to be inside it

Comment: actually see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65148062/2208713 - I've just cobbled together something that does this for me