# Create a custom Show Layout component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I'm trying to create a custom layout component, so I can design my `Show` page better.

I'm not sure why some things work and some don't. My plan is to use the `Material-UI` `<Grid>` component. I know that the `Grid` component doesn't pass the props, then I'm extending to my own:

```
export default function OrderShow(props) {
    return (
        <Show {...props}>
            <CustomGrid>
                <TextField source="shortId" label="Short ID" />
            </CustomGrid>
        </Show>
    );
}
```

My `CustomGrid` component, which is just a draft yet, is cloning its children to pass the props:

```
function CustomGrid(props) {
    return React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => React.cloneElement(child, props));
}
```

When I use it, the `TextField` receives the `source`, and renders it correctly. However the `label` is gone. I'm not sure why this happens.

Another problem is that when I try to use the `CustomGrid` with a `ReferenceField`, it doesn't work at all:

```
<Show {...props}>
  <CustomGrid>
    <ReferenceField source="user" reference="users" label="Name" link="show">
      <FunctionField render={(record) => `${record.firstName} ${record.lastName}`} />
    </ReferenceField>
  </CustomGrid>
</Show>
```

I can see that the props are passed until the `ReferenceField`, but it's lost before reaching the `FunctionField`:

[image: props ok]

[image: props lost]

Is there a better way to customize the `SimpleShowLayout` and continue using the `TextField` and other components from `react-admin`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I have more complex layouts in \`react-admin\` "Show" and "Edit" and "Create" screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992309/how-do-i-have-more-complex-layouts-in-react-admin-show-and-edit-and-creat)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. Simply put `react-admin`'s `SimpleShowLayout` is a little bit more coplex then just passing the props to the children fields. That's why you have to recursively iterate until you reach a field and perform the stuff the `react-admin` does.

Finally I have decided to share some privately developed components in a new package I am building. I have added layouts which work both with `Box` and `Grid` `material-ui`'s components. You can have a look here: [ra-compact-ui](https://github.com/ValentinnDimitroff/ra-compact-ui)

Comment: Nice! I solved my problem using the `useShowController` hook and passing the props needed by the components